# problem with achartengine when integrate with database

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using `achartengine` to draw chart which will updated when new value is inserted into database.

```
chart()
{
 if (mChartView == null) 
 {          
  d = new BuildMultipleDataset();           
  db.open();

  //code for some database query            
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
  mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, d.datasetbuilder(cursor1,cursor2), d.render());
  layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, chartHeight));      

  db.close();       
 }
 else 
 {
  mChartView.repaint();
 }
}
```

I call this method when a update is triggered from database. and in that time I make mChartView = null; But the problem is that it does not draw the updated chart. update is reflected into chart only when if I switch screen orientation. what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

I was only able to get this to work when I removed the View, set `mChartView = null;`, defined `mChartView`, and the set the View.

i.e.

```
layout.removeView(mChartView);
mChartView = null;
mChartView = ChartFactory //rest of mChartView code
layout.addView(mChartView);
```